# Bootstrap nested unordered lists without inheritance

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a CSS/HTML timeline like this one: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/97QeW

It uses an unordered list to join the timeline cards. I now need to insert an unordered list inside the cards body and what happens is that the identation and the bullet icons type are inherited from the top-level card ul/li.

How can I reset or isolate a ul/li style inside the cards?

The snippet shows both what I'm getting now and what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove bullets:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

you can also assign a class to isolate, as it is in your shared snippet would be a circle:

```
ul.class {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

ul.ul2 {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>foo</li>
  <ul class="ul2">
    <li>
      bar
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to target the unordered list is like so:

```
ul li > ul li {
  list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but nothing changes when I add your solution to the snippet CSS.